# Moovweb - uncompress gzipped outgoing_response.http content?

Tags: gzip, moovweb, tritium

I have a Moovweb project and I'm trying to compare the incoming_response.http and outgoing_response.http files in tmp/messages/... folders.

The incoming_response.http from the upstream server is saved in plain text, 
but the outgoing_response.http file is gzipped content!

How can I convert it to plain text so I can look through the response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this in your main.ts files:

```
export("disable_compression", "true")
```

Comment: Just putting this code in also works: `$disable_compression = "true"`